# What's the name of the "warbling" vocal technique in "The Tale of Jenny and Screech"?

Tags: technique, voice

In a song by Ren, called *The Tale of Jenny and Screech*, there's a musical technique that I've heard a few times over the years, but never known the name of it (if it has one, as I'm sure it does).  It's somewhat between a trill and a warble, if I had to hazard a guess at descriptive terms for it.  It has the sound of a higher-pitched sound (being made in the throat, from my own practice at trying to make it), and a vibration of the tongue and/or lips.

I don't have a better description, so I'll link the time-tagged video [here](https://youtu.be/TYAnqQ--KX0?t=23).  It starts within ~1 sec of that time tag, and lasts for perhaps 15 seconds at most.

Comment: Sounds like it might be related to the [mouth trumpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouth_trumpet) that was made famous by Jazz musicians.  Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDwANQkiC2w

Answer (score 2):

This is a combination of two techniques.

The most prominent is variously known as a **lip trill**, **lip roll**, **lip bubble** (see [The Secret of Lip Trills Unveiled](https://www.monikawelchvocalcoaching.co.uk/blog/the-secret-of-lip-trills-unveiled/#:%7E:text=A%20lip%20trill%20is%20a,a%20%27snort%2Dblow%27.)), **lip flutter** (see [Voice Exercises: The Lip Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AR-ow2e7lzE)), and **bubble lips** (see [Power to Sing Live #98: Singing Technique Tip - Bubble Lips vs Tongue Trill vs Larynx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELy5FPQP_kM), likely among others. The technique involves relaxing the lips so that they "flap" when blown through. The sound, when done with simple blowing rather than singing, is similar to the sound of a horse fluttering its nostrils. Singers often use the technique as a warm-up, and brass players often use it both as a warm-up and as a cool-down.

The second technique is **vibrato**, which is a natural result of relaxed vocal cords. The singer applies it a few times in addition to the lip flutter.